# Make a map of density out of list of coordinates and density

Tags: python, maps, coordinates

On Python, I need to create a map of density out of 3 lists: a list of density, and 2 list of coordinates in longitude and latitude.
It's organized like this: the first density coordinates are the first element of latitude and longitude lists.

The only way I found is to use matplotlib.scatter with colorbar, but I'd like to know if there was better ways to do it ?

I tried seaborn.heatmap, but I did not succeed at making a proper dataframe out of my lists.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, but first things first: you should be more precise. it seems you are asking about solution in Python, right? (please specify it, at minimum as tag), else we may think you are asking just conceptuality (so mathematics). As I understand the problem, you have a scatter plot (x,y, density). You may put a picture as example, if you want something different. Maybe a heat map style?

Comment: Oh yeah sorry, I forgot to mention it was on python.
Well I did a scatter plot but I would like to try others ways, such as heatmap indeed. For that one, I tried seaborn.heatmap, but I did not achieved to make a proper 2d dataset out of my lists...